# Cannot connect ros master when run with sudo

Tags: ros, master, sudo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the title, I can run well a bag normally, but when I add sudo, it says

```
[FATAL] [1471510924.482740850]: ROS_MASTER_URI is not defined in the environment.
```

which is the same as no master exists. But I really have to add sudo to open a usb camera.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241945/cannot-connect-ros-master-when-run-with-sudo/) by [xyz](https://answers.ros.org/users/27624/xyz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the following answers:

Reason why what you want to do is not working: http://answers.ros.org/question/194247/how-to-launch-sudo-rosrun/

Possible workaround for exact same usecase you have: http://answers.ros.org/question/165246/launch-node-with-root-permissions/

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-18**:
I'd actually suggest *not* to run anything as root (so don't use `sudo`). In most cases it's not necessary, and only the access rights of the user need to be changed. See [Rosrun as super user](http://answers.ros.org/question/189457) fi (but there are many more).